Playing audio messages that come as cloudKey in mp4 format with mediaPlayer
This code is needed to implement MediaPlayer functionality. Since the project itself is multiplatform.
class AudioPlayerImp(private val client: HttpClient) : AudioPlayer {
    private var mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer? = null
    private var playerState: PlayerState = PlayerState.IDLE

    override suspend fun play(audioUrl: String) {
        stop()

        val downloadsDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
        val fileName = audioUrl.split("/").last()
        val filePath = "${downloadsDir.absolutePath}/$fileName"
        val file = File(filePath)
        if (!file.exists()) {
            client.downloadAndSave(audioUrl, fileName)
            return
        }

        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer().apply {
            setDataSource(filePath)
            setOnPreparedListener {
                setPlayerState(PlayerState.PREPARED)
                // Начать воспроизведение после подготовки
                if (getPlayerState() == PlayerState.PREPARED) {
                    start()
                    setPlayerState(PlayerState.PLAYING)
                }
            }
            setOnBufferingUpdateListener { _, percent ->
                if (getPlayerState() == PlayerState.COMPLETED || getPlayerState() == PlayerState.PAUSED) {
                    return@setOnBufferingUpdateListener
                }
                if (!isPlaying && percent >= 50) { // Порог буферизации в 50%
                    if (getPlayerState() == PlayerState.PREPARED) {
                        start()
                        setPlayerState(PlayerState.PLAYING)
                    }
                }
            }
            setOnCompletionListener {
                setPlayerState(PlayerState.COMPLETED)
            }
            setOnErrorListener { _, what, extra ->
                setPlayerState(PlayerState.ERROR)
                true  Ошибка обработана
            }
            prepareAsync()
        }
    }
}

These is an excerpt from the logs:
Expecting binder but got null!
initFromDataSource, cannot create extractor!
Failed to init from data source!
error (1, -2147483648)
Error (1,-2147483648)

This picture shows what form my request comes in. I put it into my data class:


Have you tried LexiLabs' Basic-Sound library yet?  It builds a MediaPlayer exactly like this  and it implements iOS and JS.  https://github.com/LexiLabs-App/basic

Wow it looks like it might help me.

Seems like your MediaPlayer is never initialized.
My bet is that it is breaking during the mediaPlayer apply statement.
Are you certain that MediaPlayer can open/play the file you're passing to it? Full list is here: https://developer.android.com/media/platform/supported-formats
EDIT:
You want your player to fail gracefully.  I would implement it closer to the way LexiLabs does it. You want to add a way to throw useful errors.

Thank you, now I actually get a clear error. Do you happen to know how to solve it?
Process: io.eduonline.devrush.devrushlmsmultiplatform.androidApp, PID: 19515
java.io.FileNotFoundException: OUR6G_IgJkCvBg5qurB2Ag/audios/FpHO919GeEOCgM52fnuq9g.m4a: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
